# Type specific constructor for generic class

Tags: java, generics

I have the following generic class:

```
public class DropdownItem<V, D> {

    private V value;
    private D display;

    public DropdownItem(V value, D display) {
        this.value = value;
        this.display = display;
    }

    public V getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(V value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public D getDisplay() {
        return display;
    }

    public void setDisplay(D display) {
        this.display = display;
    }
}
```

How do I create a constructor for specific types?

For example,

```
public DropdownItem(CustomClass custom) {
    this(custom.getFoo(), custom.getBar());
}
```

or

```
public DropdownItem(CustomClass custom) {
    this.value = custom.getFoo();
    this.display = custom.getBar();
}
```

Neither of those solutions work.  It does work to do this when implementing the generic class:

```
DropdownItem<Integer, String> myItem = new DropdownItem<Integer, String>(custom.getFoo(), custom.getBar());
```

However, I would like to include a constructor in the generic class to accomplish this.  Any ideas?

Comment: in your first constructor, you can use `if (value instanceof CustomClass) { // do stuff }`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sorry about that.  Question has been fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a factory method, in addition to the existing constructor, can help you:

```
public static DropdownItem<Integer, String> getCustomClassInstance(CustomClass custom)
{
    return new DropdownItem<Integer, String>(custom.getFoo(), custom.getBar());
}
```

It can't be another constructor.  Your class is generic, so any constructor must deal with generic types `V` and `D` to assign them to `value` and `display`.  it can't be specific types in the constructor(s) for this generic class.

Comment: this worked really well.  I dropped the factory method inside the custom class, which is actually just an enum.