# Overload the Constructor of the generic class, Based on Type

Tags: c#, generics, constructor

I am trying to overload a constructor besides default constructor, which will get called for only type int. The closest thing I got is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977867/type-specific-constructor-for-generic-class).

If it is not possible, why is that?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        //default construcotr get called
        var OGenerics_string = new Generics<string>();

        //how to make a different construcotr for type int
        var OGenerics_int = new Generics<int>();
    }

    class Generics<T>
    {
        public Generics()
        {
        }
        // create a constructor which will get called only for int
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't really do that, and it's a bit of a code smell too.

Answer (score 8):

It's not possible to overload the constructor (or any method) based on the generic type - but you could create a *factory method*:

```
class Generics<T>
{
    public Generics()
    {
    }

    public static Generics<int> CreateIntVersion()
    {
          /// create a Generics<int> here
    }
}
```

Short of that, you'd have to check the generic type in the shared constructor using reflection and branch the code, which would be fairly ugly.

Answer (score 4):

You can find out passed type and if its int - do some logic

```
void Main()
{
    new Generics<string>();
    new Generics<int>();
}

class Generics<T>
{
    public Generics()
    {
        if(typeof(T) == typeof(int)) InitForInt();
    }

    private void InitForInt()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Int!");      
    }
    // create a constructor which will get called only for int
}
```